# Validação de email junto a senha com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validação

Preciso dar um alerta quando der "tudo certo" no meu formulário.
A situação é que eu preciso verificar sem o email possui "@" e "." e também junto com isso se os dois campos de senha tem valores iguais.
Eis o código.

```
$("#passo2_cad").click(function() {

    email = $("#user_email").val();
    filtro = /^([\w-\.]+@@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    senha = $("#user_password").val();
    senha_confirma = $("#user_confirm_password").val();


    if (senha === '' && senha_confirma === '' && email === '') {
        $("#user_password").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
        $("#user_confirm_password").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
    } else if (!filtro.test(email)) {
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
    } else if (senha === senha_confirma && filtro.test(email)) {
        $("#user_password").css({
            border: '2px solid #70e870'
        })
        $("#user_confirm_password").css({
            border: '2px solid #70e870'
        })
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid #70e870'
        })
        alert("Deu tudo certo!");
    }

})
```

Só que tá meio que enrolando pra caramba, valida uma coisa, trava em outra, o que tem mais de errado aí?

**OBS: Não é um submit, estou fazendo por etapas, a etapa 1 você precisa colocar o email e a senha, só quando estiver de acordo as informações que você pode passar para a etapa 2, por isso quero validar dessa forma**

Comment: Recomendo vc usar este plugin: https://jqueryvalidation.org/
vai te auxiliar na validação e muito mais pratico de trabalhar!

Comment: JQuery validation, para a validação ->
https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation Sweet Alert, para o alerta -> https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - Aqui seu código em execução e os erros encontrados!**

- Filtro errado, com 2 @ (corrigido para dar continuidade aos testes)
- No primeiro `if` se todos os campos forem nulos funciona ok.
- Outras situações no primeiro `if` baubau.
- Na primeira condicional `} else if (!filtro.test(email)) {`
  se digitar email errado e demais campos nulos também OK. Obs: coloquei para dar cor azul nas bordas do campo email nessa condicional.
- No segundo `else if` se digitar email correto <sub>passa pelo primeiro else if</sub> e demais campos nulos vai dar como `Deu tudo certo!`
  porque essa condicional `} else if (senha === senha_confirma && filtro.test(email)) {` é verdadeira  ou seja, `senha === senha_confirma` <sub>senha e confirma senha nulos são iguais</sub> e email está correto.

```js
$("#passo2_cad").click(function() {

    email = $("#user_email").val();
    filtro = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    senha = $("#user_password").val();
    senha_confirma = $("#user_confirm_password").val();


    if (senha === '' && senha_confirma === '' && email === '') {
        $("#user_password").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
        $("#user_confirm_password").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid red'
        })
    } else if (!filtro.test(email)) {
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid blue'
        })
    } else if (senha === senha_confirma && filtro.test(email)) {
        $("#user_password").css({
            border: '2px solid #70e870'
        })
        $("#user_confirm_password").css({
            border: '2px solid #70e870'
        })
        $("#user_email").css({
            border: '2px solid #70e870'
        })
        alert("Deu tudo certo!");
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input size="42" value="" id="user_email" placeholder="Email">
 <input size="42" type="password" value="" id="user_password" placeholder="Senha">
 <input size="42" type="password" value="" id="user_confirm_password" placeholder="Confirma senha">
 <button id="passo2_cad">Verificar</button>
```

**2 - Exemplo de validação correta**

> Coloquei `$(document).ready(function() {` no script pois nunca se sabe onde o script foi colocado na página, com essa linha pode colocar o script em qualquer lugar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#passo2_cad").click(function(){
   
      var email = $("#user_email").val();
      // filtros
      var emailFilter=/^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
      var ilegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/
   
      var senha = $("#user_password").val();
      var senha_confirma = $("#user_confirm_password").val();
   
      if(!senha || !senha_confirma || !email){
         if(!(emailFilter.test(email))||email.match(ilegalChars)){
            $("#user_email").css('border', '2px solid red');
            alert("email incorreto!");
            $( "#user_email" ).focus();
            return;
         }else{
            $("#user_email").css('border', '2px solid #70e870');
         }
   
         if((!senha)||(senha.length<4)){
            $("#user_password").css('border', '2px solid red');
            $("#user_password").attr("placeholder", "Minimo de 4 caracteres!");
            $( "#user_password" ).focus();
            return;
         }else{
            $("#user_email").css('border', '2px solid #70e870');
         }
      
         if(senha_confirma){
            $("#user_confirm_password").css('border', '2px solid red');
            return;
         }else{
            $("#user_email").css('border', '2px solid #70e870');
         }
      }
   
      if(senha !== senha_confirma){
         $("#user_confirm_password").val("");
         $("#user_password").css('border', '2px solid red');
         $("#user_confirm_password").css('border', '2px solid red');
         $("#user_confirm_password").attr("placeholder", "senhas não conferem!");
         $( "#user_confirm_password" ).focus();
         return;
      }
   
      $('input[id^="user_"]').css('border', '2px solid #70e870');
      alert("Deu tudo certo!");
   
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input size="42" value="" id="user_email" placeholder="Email">
<input size="42" type="password" value="" id="user_password" placeholder="Senha">
<input size="42" type="password" value="" id="user_confirm_password" placeholder="Confirma senha">
<button id="passo2_cad">Verificar</button>
```

Comment: @dvd feito e sem errar, hahaha : D

Comment: ixi, eu editei por cima ;/

Comment: precisava daquela flag não, era só usar return;

Comment: @dvd dei uma incrementada no código!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Problema

Começo por dizer que a regex que está a utilizar para validar o email:

```
/^([\w-\.]+@@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
```

Tem um `@` a mais, e por esse motivo não funciona corretamente. Independentemente disso a lógica que tem também não funciona:

```
if (senha === '' && senha_confirma === '' && email === '') {
```

Aqui está a dizer que se estas 3 coisas acontecerem ao mesmo tempo então marca estes campos a vermelho. O que significa que se a `senha` for vazia mas a confirmação e o email não forem, já não os vai marcar a vermelho.

O que significa que a seguir vai testar o `email`, mesmo podende este ser vazio:

```
...
} else if (!filtro.test(email)) {
```

E de seguida testar novamente o `email` com a regex, e comparar as senhas:

```
} else if (senha === senha_confirma && filtro.test(email)) {
```

Quando na verdade é possível que o usuário tivesse deixado ou a `senha` ou a `senha_confirma` vazia, que o não entrava no primeiro `if`.

### Solução

Uma solução pegando mais ou menos na lógica que tem é testar cada campo em separado e marcar com a cor apropriada, consoante esteja certo ou não. De forma a poder perceber se todos estão certos também precisa de mais lógica.

Exemplo:

```
//variavel para saber se algum não está correto
let erros = false; 

if (senha === '' || senha !== confirma_senha) {
    $("#user_password").css({
        border: '2px solid red'
    });
}
else {
    $("#user_password").css({
        border: '2px solid #70e870'
    });
    erros = true;
}

//falta aqui a mesma lógica para a confirmacao da senha
//que não coloquei para não ser extenso

if (email === '' || !email.test(filtro)) {
    $("#user_email").css({
        border: '2px solid red'
    });
}
else {
    $("#user_email").css({
        border: '2px solid #70e870'
    });
    erros = true;
}

if (erros === false){
    //tudo certo
}
```

Neste exemplo a variável erros memoriza se algum campo para trás tem erros e caso tenha não faz o cadastro com sucesso. Embora esta lógica funcione,e seja de certa forma parecida à sua, é muito repetida e duplica bastante o código.

Para contornar este problema podemos utilizar arrays memorizando todos os campos a serem testados. Isto facilita a aplicação dos estilos em massa. No intuito de aproveitar esta lógica também os erros podem ser guardados num array:

```js
//todos os campos existentes num array
const campos = [$("#user_email"), $("#user_password"), $("#user_confirm_password")];

$("#passo2_cad").click(function() {
    email = $("#user_email").val();
    filtro = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    senha = $("#user_password").val();
    senha_confirma = $("#user_confirm_password").val();

    let erros = []; //erros agora é um array para os campos errados
    
    if (senha === '' || senha !== senha_confirma){
        erros.push($("#user_password")); //se errado adiciona ao array de erros
    }        
    if (senha_confirma === '' || senha_confirma !== senha){
        erros.push($("#user_confirm_password")); 
    }
    if (email === '' || !filtro.test(email)){
        erros.push($("#user_email"));
    }
    
    //marcar todos os campos a verde
    for (let campo of campos){
        campo.css({border: '2px solid #70e870'});
    }
    
    if (erros.length === 0){
        alert("Deu tudo certo!");
    }
    else { //não deu certo, logo marca os errados a vermelho
        for (let campoErrado of erros){
            campoErrado.css({border: '2px solid red'});
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Email <input type="email" id="user_email"><br>
Password <input type="password" id="user_password"><br>
Confirmação <input type="password" id="user_confirm_password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="passo2_cad">
```

Neste cenário já muita da duplicação de código foi eliminada, deixando-o mais pequeno, fácil de manter e adicionar outros campos.

Como próximo passo será importante colocar a informação do que correu mal em cada passo da validação, para que o usuário não fique perdido tentando achar o que não fez certo.